# Как создать button без фона и границ?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вся суть в заголовке. Нужна кнопка, которая бы отображалась как текст определенного цвета. Пытаюсь создать. В свойствах все кроме "Foreground" делаю прозрачным, но вокруг кнопки остается серая рамка которую не получается убрать. Кроме того, кнопка начинает мигать если на нее навести или кликнуть. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать `TextBlock`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Потому что нужно проверять, что на элемент нажали.

Comment: просто обрабатывайте событие нажатия

Comment: @FoggyFinder Объясните пожалуйста как это сделать. У кнопки я вижу в обработчике событий "Click", а у TextBlock'a такого нет. Как быть?

Comment: я имею ввиду использовать `MouseLeftButtonUp` или `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`

Comment: или использовать `MouseBinding` если нужна команда

Comment: @FoggyFinder Благодарю, попробую)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF есть традиция отделять контент от представления. Если вам нужна по смыслу кнопка, используйте кнопку. Если нужно изменить её отображение, используйте стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LightweightButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

И применяйте к вашей кнопке:

```
<Button Click="OnClick" Style="{StaticResource LightweightButton}">
    Attack!
</Button>
```

---

С другой стороны, возможно, вам не нужна кнопка, а нужно «приклеить» обработчик нажатия на текст. Выбирайте сами, как правильно для вашего кода.

Если для вас вдруг более правильным является использование `TextBlock`'а, можно «повесить» обработчик на `MouseLeftButtonDown` или (возможно, более правильно) на `MouseLeftButtonUp`.